# Resume cp that was interrupted

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome-terminal, rsync, cp

I was doing a huge `cp` command, copying 1TB and I had disconnected computer from network after 700GB. Files are still there but I can't anyhow to resume copying. I tried

```
sudo rsync rsync --ignore-existing -raz --progress /media/hdd/tshirtmafia/ /home/app/tshirtmafia/
```

But it freezes. Is there any way to resume copying ?

Comment: Check this link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44189/resume-interrupted-copying-process

Comment: I would use rsync ;)

Comment: It is going to take a while to read and check a tb of data so you just need to give it time.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull, an interrupted `cp` leaves any file that was interrupted in a partial state (say only x% got copied).

If you use `rsync --ignore-existing`, this broken (because partial) file does not get updated and you have data corruption as far as equality of source and destination is concerned.